# Определение количества вхождений элемента в дерево

Tags: c++, дерево

```
int counter(Node * Root, int E)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (Root) {
        if (Root->data == E) {
            count++;
        }
        Root = Root->LeftBranch;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Код для поиска числа вхождений минимального элемента в дерево.
Всегда возвращает 1. Помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы так (не компилировал, но идея, думаю, понятна):

```
int counter(Node * Root, int E)
{
    if (Root == 0) return 0;
    return (Root->data == E) + counter(Root->LeftBranch,E) + counter(Root->RightBranch,E)
}
```

Ну, тут ищет и в правом поддереве, ну а то, что всегда возвращает 1 - так, может, у вас там и в самом деле только один искомый элемент? :)